# Testing LiveData using PowerMockRunner

Tags: android, kotlin, powermockito, android-livedata

My local unit tests use LiveData all the time. Normally, when you try to set a value on MutableLiveData you get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.
```

because local JVM has no access to Android framework. I fixed that using that:

```
@get:Rule
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Everything was fine, until I had to use PowerMockito to mock a static method from google play library. Since I added

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Tasks::class)
```

above my test class declaration I started to get this Looper not mocked error again. I used this rule before with *MockitoJUnitRunner* and everything was fine.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356314/android-rxjava-2-junit-test-getmainlooper-in-android-os-looper-not-mocked-runt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A bit late for the answer, but just faced the same issue and solved it!

To use `PowerMock` and `InstantTaskExecutorRule` you need to add the following annotation:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(MockitoJUnitRunner::class) //this line allows you to use the powermock runner and mockito runner
@PrepareForTest(UnderTestClass::class)
class UnderTestClassTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Comment: I wouldn't come up with that. Thanks!

Comment: Yo. you are a life saver.

Comment: the sample is in Kotlin, what is the error you are getting

Comment: Your solution worked adding the following line.      @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(MockitoJUnitRunner::class) //this line allows you to use the powermock runner and mockito runner
Made it work all

Answer (score 1):

No need to fret as it turns out you can still use this method to test your LiveData observers!

First, add this dependency in your module’s `build.gradle` file:

```
testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

Make sure you use the same version as the rest of your android.arch.* dependencies!

Then, in the test class where you need to call `setValue()` and assert, add this field:

```
@Rule
public TestRule rule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

For **Kotlin**

```
@get:Rule
var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Behind the scenes, this bypasses the main thread check, and immediately runs any tasks on your test thread, allowing for immediate and predictable calls and therefore assertions.

Already have this answer [here](https://medium.com/pxhouse/unit-testing-with-mutablelivedata-22b3283a7819).

Comment: I already use this Rule. The problem is since I use PowerMockRunner this Rule has no effect. I started to get this exception again, as if I would not use this rule at all. It worked fine as long as I used regular MockitoJUnitRunner, but in this test I need to use that one.