# RxJava observeOn / subscribeOn works only in test environment

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java, subscriber

I have this `AsyncSubject`

```
val asyncSubject = AsyncSubject.create<Int>()
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .subscribe(asyncSubject)
```

If I do something like this in test environment (androidTest folder)

```
asyncSubject.subscribe{
    // enter only in test environment
}
```

it enters only during testing, but I ran the same code in an activity it doesn't enter.

The only way to made it work both test and normal environment is to remove:

```
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

What I am doing wrong?

Those are my dependencies:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
```

EDIT:

it appears that it doesn't work only if I try to change an outside variable.
An example:

```
val observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val asyncSubject = AsyncSubject.create<Int>()
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(asyncSubject)
val signal = CountDownLatch(5)
var i = 0
asyncSubject.subscribe{
    i = it
    signal.countDown()
}
signal.await()
// After that `i` is always 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run java unit tests, you can't execute `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

What you can do is create a test rule to be able to execute the unit tests in a synchronous way.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43356315/5661680) you will find a detailed explanation.

You can take rule from [here](https://gist.github.com/starkej2/c446012d540b8e25409fa525c6d17cb1).

Comment: the problem is that it works only in testing environment. If I normally run the app, it won't work. Take a look at the edit to see what I mean.

Comment: I think that you should observeOn in main thread and subscribeOn on newThread. If you try to modify UI out of main thread, you will have a crash or nothing will happen.

Comment: I edited the question and try to switch. Nothing happened. The problem seems that I cannot change a variable outside the scope of the subscriber

Comment: Hey. I was really curious about this and I tested in a sample activity and I found the reason: asyncSubject is observing value in main thread, but you are blocking main thread in signal.await(). If you execute asyncSubject.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe, then it will work.
Anyway, I don't know what is your intention, but I'm sure that you can find a simple solution using rxjava operators. CountDownLatch probably is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should `sbscribe` to your `asyncSubject` prior to calling subscribe on `observable`. Also, `Observable.just(..)` doesn't honour schedulers, so your `subscribeOn/observeOn` wont have an effect here.

Comment: But if I add observeOn and subscribeOn in actual code it doesn't work, conversely to test environment.

Comment: nothing. It's like the the `subscribe` method never gets called. Only if avoid to assign  or call outside variable works(so for example print something inside onNext, onComplete. In this case it works)